# How do you make this delayed and not show until 16 seconds have passed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code below makes a box slide out when a user scrolls down to a certain point on the page... Is it possible to have the slider not show until 16 seconds have passed?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var distanceTop = $('#last').offset().top - $(window).height();

        if  ($(window).scrollTop() > distanceTop)
            $('#slidebox').animate({'right':'0px'},300);
        else
            $('#slidebox').stop(true).animate({'right':'-430px'},100);
    });

    $('#slidebox .close').bind('click',function(){
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it by `setTimeout`

```
setTimeout(function(){
 $('#slidebox').animate({'right':'0px'},300);
},1000*16);
```

Comment: Just tried this out and worked perfectly! thank you! very helpful!

Comment: All of this works perfectly thank you! ?... is there a way to add a button/link that says "OPT OUT" and when you click it, it won't show the slider to users anymore?

Comment: Yes you can use hide() method onclick of OUTPUT button